# VMware HTML Console SDK connection failed

Tags: websocket, vmware, vnc, vmware-tools

Hello VMware Community,

I'm encountering an issue when trying to connect to an HTML console via WebSocket. Below is the process I followed and the error I'm experiencing. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Using Python, I retrieved VNC connection information for a virtual machine. The code snippet used is as follows:

```
try:
    ticket = vm.AcquireMksTicket()
    print("VNC connection information for {}:".format(vm_name))
    print("Host: {}".format(ticket.host))
    print("Port: {}".format(ticket.port))
    print("Ticket: {}".format(ticket.ticket))
    print("SSL thumbprint: {}".format(ticket.sslThumbprint))
except vmodl.MethodFault as e:
    print("Failed to get VNC connection information: {}".format(e.msg))
    exit(1)
```

This resulted in the following

```
VNC connection information for dev-test - 10.xxxxxxxxxxxx:
Host: ch1-dev-esxi1.lab.local
Port: 902
Ticket: 52xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
SSL thumbprint: [Thumbprint]
```

Issue:

However, when attempting to use this information to connect to the HTML console, I'm facing a WebSocket connection failure. The error message is:

**WebSocket connection to 'wss://[IP]:[Port]/ticket/[Ticket-ID]' failed**

Here's the HTML and JavaScript code I used for the connection:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
... [Rest of the HTML code] ...
<script>
var wmks = WMKS.createWMKS("wmksContainer",{})
  .register(WMKS.CONST.Events.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE, function(event, data){
    if(data.state == WMKS.CONST.ConnectionState.CONNECTED){
      console.log("connection state change: connected");
    }
  });
wmks.connect("wss://ch1-dev-esxi1.lab.local:902/ticket/52dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Additional Checks:

The VM is running without issues.

VMware Tools are installed, current, and running (Version 12288, 12.0.0).

I'm unsure why this WebSocket connection is failing. Has anyone experienced a similar issue or can provide some insights into what might be going wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: A VNC Server is not a WebSocket server. Why are you trying to connect via WebSockets to a VNC server?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Whats the alternate way I could use? I am currently using https://developer.vmware.com/web/sdk/2.1.0/html-console/. My goal to show VM Console in my web application.

Comment: There is a project called [noVNC](https://github.com/novnc/noVNC) which is the vnc protocol implementation for browsers. You need a WebSocket to TCP bridge to use it. Also from the novnc group: https://github.com/novnc/websockify Interesting project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved now. The issue was related to ticket that was created by following line in my Python Script

```
ticket = vm.AcquireMksTicket()
```

I replaced above line with the following line.

```
 ticket = vm.AcquireTicket(ticketType='webmks')
```

AcquireMksTicket only works with very old vSphere versions.